# TSQL Limit result when completing a distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to limit this query to return only the top10 result from a distinct count. I still want it to complete a count over everything, but limit the result to the top 10 mycount

Thank you

```
SELECT
   distinct count(TagName) as mycount
  ,[Area]
  ,[TagName]
  ,[Description]


  FROM [A2ALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmHistory]
  where value = 'true' and 
  eventstamp between '20160203' and '20160210'
  group by area,TagName, Description
  order by mycount desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `top 10`?

```
SELECT TOP 10 count(TagName) as mycount, [Area], [TagName], [Description]
FROM [A2ALMDB].[dbo].[v_AlarmHistory]
WHERE value = 'true' and 
      eventstamp between '20160203' and '20160210'
GROUP BY [Area], [TagName], [Description]
ORDER BY mycount DESC;
```

The appropriate way to structure the query is using `GROUP BY`, not `SELECT DISTINCT`.